# Having trouble calling a public method in a static method

Tags: c#, methods

I'm really sorry because this is probably a very newbish question, but I can't find an answer to this anywhere. 
I'm confused on how to call the function DoStuff below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public void DoStuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something...");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change the following `public void DoStuff()` to `public static void DoStuff()` if you want to call a public method inside a static void Main, you need to create a new instance of `Program` like this var prg = new Program()` then call `prg.DoStuff()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void DoStuff()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm doing something...");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

C# is an object oriented programming language which means that every member within a class. Since the static method  init before  normal method , you should define DoStuff as a static method so that it can be call within Main method. When the class has been created, the static member already init in the computer's memory, however, the non-static member will waiting to the instance of the class. In that case, the static member belong to the whole class and the non-static belong to an instance of a class. So you can use ClassName.StaticMember to call StaticMember and you need a real instance of a class to call non-staticMember. just like: new Program().DoStuff() if the DoStuff is non-static method

Comment: it would be better explained as the difference between `Instance Method vs Static Method`

Comment: thanks for your advices MethodMan, My c# book is not English version, But I will pay attention of it.

Comment: MSDN could have given given you a quick explanation with or without a book

Answer (score 3):

`public void` is an Instance method. There is an implicit, hidden parameter to the function called `this`.

`public static void` is a Static method. There is no implicit `this` parameter.

Your `DoStuff` method does not use the `this` reference, so change it to `public static void DoStuff`.

Answer (score 2):

do a MSDN Google search on the Instance Method vs Static Method 
[Static and instance methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766(v=vs.71).aspx)

change the following:

```
public void DoStuff()
```

to public

```
public static void DoStuff()
```

> If you want to call a public method inside a static void Main, you need to create a new instance of Program like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var prg = new Program(); 
     prg.DoStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of Program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Program().DoStuff();
}
```