# How do I call a static method from final class into main class?

Tags: java, static, final

The program converts strings to and from “rövarspråket” –all consonants are duplicated and  an “o”  is  inserted between them. Vowels,  numbers and other   characters  are kept as they are. “rovar” thus becomes “rorovovaror”.

```
public final class rovar
{

    public static String lower_consonants = "bcdfhjklmnpqrstvwxz";
    public static String upper_consonants = "BCFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ";

    public static String enrov(String normal)
    {
        if (normal == null)
            return null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(char c : normal.toCharArray())
        if (lower_consonants.contains(String.valueOf(c)))
            builder.append(c + "o" + c);
        else if (upper_consonants.contains(String.valueOf(c)))
            builder.append(c + "O" + c) ;
        else
            builder.append(c);

        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static String derov(String rov)
    {
        if (rov == null)
            return null;

        for(char c : lower_consonants.toCharArray()) {
            String find = (String.valueOf(c) + "o" + String.valueOf(c));
            rov = rov.replace(find, String.valueOf(c));
        }

        for(char c : upper_consonants.toCharArray()){
            String find = (String.valueOf(c) + "O" + String.valueOf(c));
            rov = rov.replace(find, String.valueOf(c));
        }
        return rov;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to compile this program. Therefor, I have created a main class and tried to create a new instance of the class and afterwards calling the two methods.

```
public class RovarMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rovar r = new rovar();
        r.enrov();
        r.derov();

    }

}
```

**The problem is I am not sure which argument to take for those method call. Because the above two lines of code show error: *The method enrov(String) in the type rovar is not applicable for the arguments ()***

Comment: Off-topic note : please learn java naming conventions

Comment: you should call a public static method just with the class name, the link is about the C# static method, but I think Java is the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568120/having-trouble-calling-a-public-method-in-a-static-method/35568241#35568241

Answer (score 0):

As both of them are static methods you can call them without object. And both of those methods are taking parameters. code example for main method :

```
 rovar.enrov("PARAMETER_1");  rovar.derov("PARAMETER_1);
```

Comment: Md khirul ashik, thanks for your answer. My main point was what would be the parameters in my case. may be (rover.lower_consonants) &  (rover.upper_consonants)?

Comment: Both of the functions are checking for uppercase and lowercase letter. You should not change the case. Your parameter value can contain both. Or you can send it as uppercase letter and remove checking for lower case in both of the functions.

Comment: Md khirul ashik, to be honest I was failed to understand what I have to do. At the moment you see my variables (e.g. private static String lower_consonants ...) are set as "private". How would I use the variables as parameters in another class. Would it be something like this: Rovar.enrov(Rovar.lower_consonants,Rovar.upper_consonants ); ?